# SP2010 Provide Contributor Security/Permissions to Adjust the Navigation

Tags: permissions, navigation

Is there any way to allow contributor users to manage some settings on a site (for example, manage the Quick Launch order or the order of the Global Navigation) but prevent some settings from being used such as deleting the site?

We need to let users (contributors) add items and change the order of the global navigation and the quick launch area but not allow them to delete the site.

Any ideas/solutions on this will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Govgirl,

Users can "Personalize" any site as long as that feature/permission is enabled.  I'm not sure if that will let them mess with the order of navigation elements on the page, but maybe it would.

If personalization does not work in that regard, you can also try experimenting with different "Permission Levels" which let you create new groups like the standard "Contribute, Approve, Design, etc" groups.  You should be able to get to this from the ribbon in the permissions area of your site.  The problem with giving people permission to change the navigation is that the "Global Navigation" is global, so everybody would see those changes and your navigation would be all over the place all the time.

A third option would be to create some kind of customization to use lists or even the actual site navigation itself to generate a user-configurable navigation scheme.

Maybe more info is required here. Does each user have/control their own site, except for the deletion?  If that is the case you should be able to just give them that permission and be done with it.  Is it a real concern that people would be deleting sites, where you could not control this with some sort of policy or rule?

- Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt for the quick response. Unfortunately the personalization option will not work for us because we do want the navigational changes to be seen globally. I looked at creating a custom group permission but I'm worried that if I give them the option to "Manage Web Site" under "Site Permissions" it might open a can of worms by giving them too many capabilities. So that leaves me to wonder if there is another permission that will do what I want that I am overlooking??? Or, better yet, is there a way to get more granular with the permissions????

Comment: I think without customizing things in SharePoint the list you get when you try to "Add a Permission Level" is about as granular as it gets.  Unless you do that you are probably stuck with the risk involved with giving them "Manage Web Site" permission.

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid that is what I'm being faced with. I'm experimenting right now with "Add and Customize Pages" site permissions instead of the "Manage Web Site" permission and that seems to be less powerful but could be dangerous because it still allows them to get to the "Manage Content and Structure" area. Anyway I haven't given up yet!!!

Comment: Good luck and don't forget to update this if you find a solution that works out for you!  I think this is one of those areas a lot of people could be interested in.

Comment: Got the solution!!! I had to ceate a custom permission. I copied the contributor permission and created my custom "senior contributor" permission based on that and I also selected the "Add and Customize Pages" permission in that custom permission as well. That allows my user to change the navigation AND (most importantly) doesn't give them the ability to delete the site.

Comment: Good job!  You should put that as an answer so people can find this down the road!